# Implementing failover in ActiveMQ with Stomp in python

Tags: python, implementation, activemq-classic, failover, stomp

I have searched around for python stomp libraries which implement failover as well but couldn't find anyone. Also setting up pyactivemq (which the documentation says that it supports failover) is too difficult on 1000 machines (clients for running consumer program). I wanted to make a wrapper on top of the existing python stomp library so that the client can receive message in case of any of the brokers failure.

Fetching the message from any of the two brokers when one has failed is easier, we just need to use single try catch and then try to connect to other. But i am not getting how would the master know of any messages that have been fetched during failover as when the master comes up the client will again see those messages.

Any suggestions that can be made in the broker configurations for this ?

Comment: what kind of topology you are using for your master-slave brokers? If you are using a master-slave broker with shared state, only one broker would be active at any time and you don't have to worry about duplicate messages.